# Вопрос о необходимости запятой после "согласно"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Известно, что запятая после оборота с предлогом "согласно" ставится факультативно (меня интересует его употребление в самом начале предложения). Я знаю, что запятая ставится в случае, если конструкция с "согласно" или другими производными предлогами стоит между подлежащим и сказуемым или не ставится, если "согласно" тесно связано по смыслу со сказуемым ("действовать согласно закону"). Однако, поискав в Национальном корпусе русского языка, я выяснила, что в большинстве случаев запятую все же ставят. Но как быть в классических случаях? Например, если ученику попадается этот производный предлог на диктанте? В учебниках рекомендуют запятую не ставить. Но "Грамота.ру" даёт разные варианты — от обязательной запятой до ее факультативности. И как быть, если после "согласно" идут такие слова: "его словам"? Ведь в таком случае "согласно его словам" становится уже чем-то вроде вводной конструкции ("по его словам"). И напрашивается запятая. Но в то же время запятая будет противоречить рекомендации не обособлять оборот со словом "согласно" в начале.

Answer (score 2):

```
  Но в то же время запятая будет противоречить рекомендации не обособлять
  оборот со словом "согласно" в начале.
```

Правило даёт достаточную свободу, говоря о факультативном выделении оборотов с предлогом согласно, зачем же Вы сами ставите преграды? Рекомендация - это не требование. И в диктанте тоже будет учитываться факультативность. Если Вы видите в обороте дополнительный смысл - указание на источник, причину действия, любое пояснение - и при этом выделяете оборот паузами, смело ставьте запятые, никто не укажет на ошибку, несмотря на рекомендации Грамоты не выделять оборот в начале предложения. Вот почитайте ещё раз, там есть примеры и с выделением, и без выделения:

https://pishugramotno.ru/punktuacia/soglasno-zapyataya-nuzhna-ili-net